# Css Not Working After Resseting Margin and Padding

Tags: html, css

These are my html and css files and I'm facing issue with css not working after I reset margin and padding in the begining of my css so I should be getting my browser page divided into two section of 30% red and 70% white but for some reason it doesn't seem to work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fashion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="left-col"></div>
      <div class="right-col"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.hero {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left-col {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e80707;
}

.right-col {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: its working fine, there is no problem in your code, the only thing is the height of the element is 0 and you are not able to see the result due to that, add some content left and right col or try giving the height

Comment: Hi, By me it is working, your div are empty, this is why you may not see anything, because from the moment you set a content to your div or you change the height of hero class to 100vh (to test). you can see 30% / 70%

Answer (score 2):

Its working fine, you are not able to see the output just because there is nothing in your left and right col, and due to that, height is 0, try adding some content or give height to left and right col.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.hero  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.left-col{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #e80707;
}

.right-col{
    flex-basis: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fashion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="left-col">Left Col</div>
        <div class="right-col">Right Col</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```